# AWS PostgreSQL RDS much slower than Heroku PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

We're in the process of migrating some apps out of Heroku to AWS, and we've encountered a problem with the performance of the database in RDS.

We initially tried using an Aurora PostgreSQL cluster, but found it too slow. We then tried a normal RDS PostgreSQL, but it was also much slower than Heroku.

Queries are typically taking twice as long as they were in Heroku.

I've tried with standard SSD storage, and with Provisioned IOPS (SSD), but it doesn't appear to make any difference to the speed of the queries.

Can anyone suggest what I should look for, to try to figure out why RDS PostgreSQL is consistently slower than Heroku PostgreSQL.

Comment: I'd be interested if you ever found a solution for this.

Comment: @dps Not really. We ended up just re-writing a number of queries to improve the performance. We didn't figure out why Heroku seemed to be faster with the less efficient queries. Using AWS we were able to save a significant amount of money in other areas, so the migration was still cost effective.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, @user1751825.  I honestly have no idea why it is so much slower, I'll post here if I find anything interesting.  Working on this currently...

Comment: Following up on this sometime afterwards - I think this might have actually been Dyno types for us.  I would recommend trying a different Dyno size for others experiencing this problem.

Comment: is this due to the App Layer (assuming still in Heroku), needing to travel far further (read: different network)  to connect to RDS PostGre compare to Heroku PostGre?

Comment: @iwan This was a long time ago now, but if I recall correctly, we tested the queries directly against the database, so the app layer wasn't a factor. Anyway we fully moved off Heroku and the dba was able to resolve the performance issues, but I'm not sure how.